# How to count the total number of files in all sub-directories?

Tags: command-line, files, find

l have a directory called `/data/` which contains two sub-directories: `/data/train/` and `/data/test/`. `train` and `test` each contain **101** sub-directories (101 directories in `train` and 101 in `test`).

These directories contain jpeg images. I want to loop through all the directories to:

1. Count the total number of images
2. Count the number of images contained in each directory

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Read `man find`, and do something like

```sh
find /data/train /data/test -type f -print | wc -l

for dirname in $(find /data/train /data/test -type d -print) ; do
    /bin/echo -e -n "$dirname\t"
    find $dirname -type f -print | wc -l
done
```

Answer (score 4):

Python has appropriate utilities for such job built in already. As one-liner this would be done as so:

```sh
$ python -u -c 'from os import walk,path; print "\n".join([str(len(f)) +" "+r for r,d,f in walk(".")])'
```

Or as script as so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
for root,dirs,files in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    print(root,len(files))
```

Notice that in script version you're meant to call script with directory as positional parameter:

```
$ ./count_files.py my_dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

In pure `bash`:

```bsh
for dir in /data/*/; do
    files=( "$dir"/*/* )
    printf "%s\t%s\n" "$dir:" "${#files[@]}"
done
```

The output would be something like:

```
/data/test:     5432
/data/train:    1234
```